# Possibility of accesing Nested Static Folder in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

By default, Flask allows one level of nesting within the Static Folder. For instance

```
->static <BR>
---->css <BR>
------->images<BR>
```

We can access files within the css directory through the browser.

e.g. `http://localhost:5000/static/css/file1.css`

How can we access the files within images directory through the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Flask sets up the route for static files using your static path (defaults to `/static`) and any text. From the [source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/67e4d3ee63dc561eba9b4245b026f24f3cdfc70d/flask/app.py#L537-L539):

```
self.add_url_rule(self.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
    endpoint='static',
    view_func=self.send_static_file)
```

[`send_to_static`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/67e4d3ee63dc561eba9b4245b026f24f3cdfc70d/flask/helpers.py#L871-L872) passes whatever this route assigns to `filename`.

```
return send_from_directory(self.static_folder, filename,
    cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
```

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/67e4d3ee63dc561eba9b4245b026f24f3cdfc70d/flask/helpers.py#L617) for `send_from_directory` you will see that it just uses `safe_join(directory, filename)` to get the path to the file.

[`safe_join`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/67e4d3ee63dc561eba9b4245b026f24f3cdfc70d/flask/helpers.py#L579-L587) itself just does some work to normalize the path and watch out for things like `..` in the filename.

Going back to the [URL route](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations), `path` matches any text. It's like `string` except it accepts slashes. This means that you can use any level of nesting within your static folder. URLs like `/static/file.txt` and `/static/p/a/t/h/t/o/file.txt` will all work. So long as the URLs begin with your static path, the behavior you want works out of the box:

```
http://localhost:5000/static/css/images/image1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, where you find, Flask allows just one level of nesting.

Just try it.

I have directory `./static/html/jobs.html` and I get this served on url `http://localhost:5000/static/html/jobs.html`.